# Android jsoup does not get complete HTML document

Tags: android, jsoup

I am getting external html document using Jsoup but Jsoup get only half of html documnet. Here is my http://www.myanmarinternetjournal.com/content/8287

May I know what header do I need to add?

Thanks Alex

protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String data = "";
            Document doc = null;
            doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0])
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .get();
            Log.e("RssDetailsActivity", doc.toString());
            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("content clearfix");
            for(Element element : elements) {
                data += element.outerHtml();
                data += "<br/>";
            }             

            return data;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RssDetailsActivity", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to my question.

Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("content clearfix");

I am adding the wrong class. I should only put "content".

Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("content");

After that I got the div part. I just realize that doc value in debug mode is cut off in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, then right click and select "Inspect element". There is will be a tab called as "Network". Look for the right call that give you the html content. Once you click on that you should be able to see the Request Header and Response Header. Below is a snippet of Request header

```
GET /content/8287 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myanmarinternetjournal.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: has_js=1; __qca=P0-306326763-1379867776215; __utma=26494267.256134586.1379867776.1379867776.1379867776.1; __utmb=26494267.1.10.1379867776; __utmc=26494267; __utmz=26494267.1379867776.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=168333117.107878997.1379867784.1379867784.1379867784.1; __utmb=168333117.1.10.1379867784; __utmc=168333117; __utmz=168333117.1379867784.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _pk_id.6.0010=447ba0a1b9e46537.1379867784.1.1379867784.1379867784.; _pk_ses.6.0010=*; __unam=688c865-14146878987-1b969d4c-1
```

Using this fill in more header parameters into you jsoup.connect() call.
You can do that same with firebug extension on firefox.